Client Certificate required for LDAP
Is it required to have a client certificate installed for establishing LDAPS connection to an LDAP Server? I am receiving the error " no client certificate to authenticate" while attempting to connect.

It’s required by your  LDAP server because that’s how it’s configured. It isn’t a general requirement.
